# Using POST to get select option value from HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select

I have a form where i get some different information. But then i have a Select with multiple options and i want to be able to send this to the database in 1 or 0 / true or false. But it is not working. This is my code so far:

```
              <select name="multipleSelect[]" multiple>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
                <option name="esea" value="esea">ESEA</option>
                <option name="faceit" value="faceit">FaceIT</option>
                <option name="matchmaking" value="matchmaking">Matchmaking</option>
              </select>
              <label>What are you looking to play?</label>
```

And this is my php:

```
$esea = 0;
$faceit = 0;
$matchmaking = 0;
foreach ( $_POST['multipleSelect'] as $value ) {
    if ( $value == 'esea' )        { $esea = 1;       }
    if ( $value == 'faceit' )      { $faceit= 1;      }
    if ( $value == 'matchmaking' ) { $matchmaking= 1; }
}   


  // Sätt in dataN
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users ( steamid, profilename, profileurl, avatar, region, age, ranks, esea, faceit, matchmaking, textarea1 ) VALUES ( 
    '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['steamid'])}', 
    '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['profilename'])}',
    '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['profileurl'])}',
    '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['avatar'])}',
    '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['region'])}',
    '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['age'])}',
    '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ranks'])}',
    $esea,
    $faceit,
    $matchmaking',
    '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['textarea1'])}')";
  $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

I know that this code doesnt work but i don't know what to do to make it work. I wan't to send a 1 or a 0 depending on if the chose the alternative or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<select>` for a multiple selectable dropdown needs to be an array, defined by `name="NameThatMakesSense[]"`

```
<select name="NameThatMakesSense[]" multiple>
```

This will then return you an field called $_POST['NameThatMakesSense'] which itself is an array containing 1 or more values indicating which items in the dropdown were selected. From the `value=""` attribute of the `<option>` tag

Then your will need to preprocess the `NameThatMakesSense` array to pick up which values were actually selected form the multi select dropdown.

```
$esea = 0;
$esea = 0;
$esea = 0;
foreach ( $_POST['NameThatMakesSense'] as $value ) {
    if ( $value == 'esea' )        { $esea = 1;       }
    if ( $value == 'faceit' )      { $faceit= 1;      }
    if ( $value == 'matchmaking' ) { $matchmaking= 1; }
}    

$sql = "INSERT INTO users 
             ( profilename, profileurl, avatar, region, 
               age, esea, faceit, matchmaking, textarea1 ) 
        VALUES ( 

'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['profilename'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['profileurl'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['avatar'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['region'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['age'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ranks'])}',
$esea,
$faceit,
$matchmaking,
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['textarea1'])}')";
```

Comment: How do i pick this up post tho? Do I still use '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['esea'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['faceit'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['matchmaking'])}',

Comment: Thanks for you help RiggsFolly! :)

Comment: what should i put in here:      `'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST[''])}',` for it to pick up the $val?

Comment: @Tim I have amended my question to include how to process the data received from the multi select dropdown

Comment: i've updated my question with your answer but now it doesnt work at all. It's not sending any of my data to the database.

Comment: What datatype are those 3 columns on your database

Comment: tinyint 1 or 0 :) What are we sending?

Comment: A 1 or a 0, what exactly is the error you are getting

Comment: Oopppps TYPO Alert!!! I left a single quote after `$matchmaking',` that need removing

Comment: LOL! That was it thank you so much @RiggsFolly! Ur a gentleman and a scholar!

Answer (score 2):

Your `select` html tag needs to have a `name` attribute in order for the form onSubmit to send to the "backend".

like so:

```
<select name="enterNameThatMakesSense" multiple>  // <----- HERE
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
  <option name="esea" value="1">ESEA</option>
  <option name="faceit" value="1">FaceIT</option>
  <option name="matchmaking" value="1">Matchmaking</option>
</select>
<label>What are you looking to play?</label>
```

Comment: And if you actually want multiple values in `$_POST` you need an array: `enterNameThatMakesSense[]`

Comment: But `<option>`  tags do not have a `name` attribute

Comment: Thank you Pedro for taking the time to help! :)